# SharePoint Online Access Requests for Users not in Directory

Tags: security, external-users

We have a requirement for users not in our O365 tenant to be able to submit an access request to our SharePoint Online site. Normally, if a user in a tenant doesn’t have access to a site, they will see an access request form; however, if the user is not already in the tenant, they instead see an error “User is not found in the directory” and there’s no option to submit an access request. It looks like we have to manually add external users to O365 AAD before they can see the access request form. 
We will be putting the SPOL URL on printed materials and need to support external users not in O365 AAD to see the access request form.